# How to exit and close the python program

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to exit/close python program?

```
import csv
import os

with open('numbers.csv', 'w+', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['name', 'lname']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'name': 'Alen', 'lname': 'Sow'})

os._exit(0)
```

## The above script doesn't close/exit the python script.

I also tried:

```
import sys
sys.exit(0)
```

## But this also didn't close/exit the python script.

Comment: You don't need to do anything; the program exits automatically after it executes the last line of code. What makes you think that the script doesn't exit?

Comment: I mean the **cmd.exe** should also be close automatically after the code is executed...., but here it is not....

Comment: @Grass That’s not up to Python or to your script, it’s up to cmd and the way you have it configured.

Comment: So, this means we cannot close cmd at all using python? @abarnert

Comment: @Grass Well, you can always `os.kill` whoever your `os.ppid` is, but that’s probably a bad idea. You’re not supposed to do things like that—if you do, someone running your program from an existing cmd window will see it disappear, running your program from inside your IDE will kill the IDE, running your program from a batch file or another Python program will kill that, etc.

Comment: Actually I need that, if the program is executed then it should ask the user for exiting the software, if yes it should close the software...@abarnert

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like so:

```
import csv

with open('numbers.csv', 'w+', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['name', 'lname']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'name': 'Alen', 'lname': 'Sow'})

exit() #or quit()
```

`sys.exit(n)` exit the code with status `n` without calling cleanup handlers.

`os._exit(n)` should normally be used in the child process after a `fork()`.

Comment: please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52208520/how-to-exit-and-close-the-python-program#comment91367624_52208520

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, `exit()` should work, although Aran-Fey is correct; it is usually not necessary.
Maybe you're getting Python mixed up with another language...